# I have a if condition, If its true write a return statement before end tag? is this better way of writing return statement in java

Tags: java

I have a if condition like the below

```
if (!null= xya)
return xya
{
a=b;
return abc
}
```

or which is it better to avoid return statement before entering in to loop

Comment: The way this is worded it is very ambiguous what you are asking, I'd rephrase it to prevent flags to close. Beyond this, your code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: I doubt that syntax works. I tried it out and double-checked. Also, I totally dont get what you are saying - your grammar is way off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused about the question, but this is how I imagine that code should look:

```
if (xya != null){
    return xya;
}
else{
    a=b;
    return abc;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what this code is meant to do, or why you need to declare `a = b` then return `abc` but if you're wondering why your code doesn't work that's probably it. As the other answer suggests, it's possible to completely remove the `else` case, but I feel like you need to keep your code as rigidly structured as possible for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your question as, "Is there a better way to write a return statement, i.e. without using an `if` block?" If this isn't what you requested, please rewrite your question, as it is very difficult to understand what you're asking.

From your code, I'm thinking that you're trying to do a null-check, and return `xyz` if it's not null. Otherwise, do some other code, and return `abc`. Let's fix your code first.

```
if (xyz != null) {
    return xyz; // Remember that after every statement, you need to have a semicolon.
} else {
    a = b;
    return abc;
}
```

You don't need to write an `else` statement within an `if` block. Knowing this, since your code would end if it `xyz` was not null, we don't need to write our code in the else statement, because the code after the `if` block is independent of the `if` block. Let's revise your code, then.

Try this:

```
if (xyz != null)
    return xyz; // Since it's only one line, brackets are optional.
a = b;
return abc;
```

If you're coming from a different language (i.e. Lua), I'd highly recommend reading some syntax tutorials on Java. It'll save you a lot of frustration later. I recommend the following [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html), and just explore and read from the beginning. It's a great way to get the basics of syntax, especially with `if` statements.

Edit:
I've been told that bracketless conditionals may hinder code readability. Here are some alternatives to writing without them:

```
if (xyz != null) {
    return xyz;
}
a = b;
return abc;
```

You could alternatively have the if statement in one line, as shown:

```
if (xyz != null) { return xyz; }
a = b;
return abc;
```

Comment: please don't recommend bracketless conditionals. IMO it makes code hard to read and somewhat ambiguous. just a suggestion

Comment: With proper whitespace, how does it make the code more difficult to read? I've never seen an example where even with proper whitespace, a bracketless conditional makes it more difficult to read (Please provide an example; I'd greatly appreciate it). I'll add in alternatives to my answer though, just in case I'm wrong.

Comment: Bracketless conditionals are VERY confusing. If you add another line of code to the conditional, the chances of messing up by not adding a bracket are pretty high.

Comment: Not for nothing, they also clutter up diffs if you're using version control. If you want to add a statement, instead of the diff showing that you added one statement, it shows that you (a) removed the `if (...)`, (b) added a very similar `if (...) {`, (c) added the statement, (d) added a `}`. Do a favor to your future self and just add those curly braces now.

Comment: I see your points. I'll make sure to include brackets in my answers.